# Insert multiple rows in access database using oledb parameters

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access-2007, oledb, vb.net-2010

I am trying to insert multiple rows in a listitems to a database using parameters.
But it won't give me any errors, and also won't insert any data in the table.
does anyone have any ideas on this one?

```
  strSQL = "insert into tbltrans2 (transid,itemcode,itemname,qty,price,[total],btw) values ( ?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Application.StartupPath + "\\POS.mdb"), _
          cmd As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, cn)

        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtTransId.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar, 10)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar, 50)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Integer)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Decimal)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Decimal)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar, 50)

        cn.Open()
        For Each ls As ListViewItem In ListItems.Items
            cmd.Parameters(1).Value = ls.Tag
            cmd.Parameters(2).Value = ls.SubItems(0).Text
            cmd.Parameters(3).Value = Integer.Parse(ls.SubItems(1).Text)
            cmd.Parameters(4).Value = Decimal.Parse(ls.SubItems(2).Text)
            cmd.Parameters(5).Value = Decimal.Parse(ls.SubItems(3).Text)
            cmd.Parameters(6).Value = ls.SubItems(5).Text
        Next ls

    End Using
```

Hey steve, When I try that, it gives me 'syntax error in update statement' erro. Here is my code:

```
 Try
        strSQL = "UPDATE set instock = ? where itemcode= ?"
        Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Application.StartupPath + "\\POS.mdb"), _
               cmd As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, cn)
            cn.Open()
            For Each ls As ListViewItem In ListItems.Items
                cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 100
                cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ls.Tag
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next ls
            cn.Close()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Now, I still need help with decreasing the stock. Here is the code that I use, but it isn't working.

```
  strSQL = "UPDATE tblitem set instock ='instock'- ? where itemcode = ?"
            Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Application.StartupPath + "\\POS.mdb"), _
                   cmd As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, cn)
                cn.Open()
                For Each ls As ListViewItem In SalesListItems.Items
                    If Not (ls.SubItems(1).Tag(0) = "n") Then
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Integer).Value = ls.SubItems(1).Text
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = ls.Tag
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    End If
                Next ls
                cn.Close()
            End Using
```

Comment: Sorry forget the table name after the UPDATE, answer updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the execute part

```
For Each ls As ListViewItem In ListItems.Items 
   cmd.Parameters(1).Value = ls.Tag 
   cmd.Parameters(2).Value = ls.SubItems(0).Text 
   cmd.Parameters(3).Value = Integer.Parse(ls.SubItems(1).Text) 
   cmd.Parameters(4).Value = Decimal.Parse(ls.SubItems(2).Text) 
   cmd.Parameters(5).Value = Decimal.Parse(ls.SubItems(3).Text) 
   cmd.Parameters(6).Value = ls.SubItems(5).Text 
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Next ls
```

Also, are you certain on the input values coming from the subitems? If there isn't a control on their effective numeric value when you add them to the ListView, then the loop could fail with an exception when you try to convert the supposed numeric value with Parse.

EDIT: This instead for an update

```
strSQL = "UPDATE tblitem set instock = ? where itemcode= ?"  
Using cn As New OleDbConnection("......")   
    cmd As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, cn)  
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 100
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = yourItemCodeValue    
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

Keep in mind that I suppose instock is a integer data type and itemcode a varchar.

Comment: is it possible to use this same method to update a database?
This is what I'm using currently:
  strSQL = String.Format(("update tblitem set inStock = '" & ls.SubItems(1).Tag - ls.SubItems(1).Text & "' where itemcode =" & ls.Tag & ""))
                        objDal.ExecuteQuery(strSQL)

Comment: ok, leave it..
How do I use parameters to update the database. like "update tblitem set instock ='value' where itemcode='value2' ?

Comment: It gives me a syntax error. I have added more details in my original question.

Comment: Thanks very much mate! It worked like a charm !! :D
This is supposed to be very fast, right? Even if I have hundreds of records in list.

Comment: Thanks mate. I did that and it worked perfect. but now I need to decrease items from stock if the transition is cancelled.
I have also put my code there above in original question. Hope you could help me with this one too. thanks

Comment: Remove the quotes around 'instock' and it should work. P.S. I suggest to post a new question. You will get more attention