# Querying Microsoft Jet Database Date Parameters

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I am trying to query a table using Microsoft Jet Database. This is the code I am using

```
SELECT orderID, OriginCustomer, OriginAddress, DestinationCustomer, DestinationAddress, purchaseOrder, productSize, referenceNumber, actionDescription, actionNote, actionDriver, actionStatus, actionColorNumber, actionDate FROM actionView 
WHERE (actionDriver = ?)
AND ( actionDate between #(?)# and #(?)#)
```

The error I get is

> Cannot convert entry to valid date/time
>   TO_DATE function might be required

I am trying to find the proper sql syntax but I can not find it or figure it out....

I am using access database

Ohh yeah forgot to mention that... I am making a Winform application through visual studio using .NET and C#. 
[image: This is a screen shot of my window if it helps...]

Comment: In what context are you running this query? Interactively within Access itself? ...from VBA code? ...from .NET code? ...?

Comment: Ohh yeah forgot to mention that... I am making a Winform application through visual studio using .NET and C#.

Comment: Are you using `OleDb`?

Comment: yes I am using OleDb.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12110294/insert-multiple-rows-in-access-database-using-oledb-parameters) and let us know if you still cannot figure it out. You're going to need to use `OleDb Paramaters`.

Comment: ohh shoot sorry then I guess I am not using OleDb. Sorry I am still an amateur:/

Comment: For all parameters (including dates) you should be able to just use question marks, i.e., `?`, with no other delimiters. See if the MSDN article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171905.aspx) provides some insight.

Comment: parameters don't need to be wrapped in `#`s, `'`s or `"`s. The sql engine already knows their data type and they are already fully contained so they don't need the extra help of these things.